# Lua filter to preserve HTML comments

Tags: lua, pandoc

I try to create a Lua filter to preserve HTML comments (but not any other HTML elements).

```lua
local function starts_with(start, str)
  return str:sub(1, #start) == start
end

function RawInline(el)
  if starts_with('<!--', el.text) then
    return el
  else
    return nil
  end
end

return {{Inline = RawInline}}
```

*(Based on mb21's answer here: [From HTML to Markdwon: As clean Markdown markup as possible, and to preserve HTML comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78052121).)*

It doesn't currently work. What might be the problem?

```bash
pandoc -f html+raw_html from.html -o to.md -t gfm --lua-filter preserve-comments.lua
```

Comment: Where do you have an end comment tag?

Comment: @Neil, could you elaborate your question? You mean that I should take into account the closing part (`-->`) in my code, not only the opening (`<!--`) one?

Comment: Exactly, where do you account for the closing of comments? what if there is a `<!--` within a comment? This is just a guess. I have not used pandoc, but it seems somehow anti-symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two small problems that prevent this filter from working. I'm listing them below and include explanations and solutions for each.

1. The main issue is `return {{Inline = RawInline}}`. This causes the `RawInline` function to be called for *all* Inline elements, such as *Str*, *Emph*, *Space*, etc. This is causing issues, because some elements don't have a `.text` attribute, and calling `starts_with` with `nil` as the second argument triggers an error.

   The solution for this is to either use `return {{RawInline = RawInline}}`, or to leave the line out entirely. Both solutions are equivalent due to the way pandoc constructs filters from global functions if no explicit filter table is returned.
2. The `RawInline` function does nothing, because `return el` and `return nil` do the same thing in this case. Not returning anything from a filter function causes pandoc to keep the object unaltered. Deleting an object is possible by returning `{}`.

To summarize, this should work:

```lua
local function starts_with(start, str)
  return str:sub(1, #start) == start
end

function RawInline(el)
  if not starts_with('<!--', el.text) then
    return {}
  end
end
```

---

To make ensure that no HTML at all is included in the output, we can use `gfm-raw_html` as the output format, i.e., we disable the `raw_html` extension. This will also suppress any HTML comment, so we modify the filter to pretend that these comments are raw Markdown, which will be included verbatim.

```lua
local function starts_with(start, str)
  return str:sub(1, #start) == start
end

function RawInline (el)
  return starts_with('<!--', el.text)
    and pandoc.RawInline('markdown', el.text) -- pretend it's md
    or {}  -- not an HTML comment, thus drop it
end
```

Comment: Many thanks. But are you sure this really works? I tried this with the following input: https://pastebin.com/raw/nHCxp7vk, and I get the following output: https://pastebin.com/raw/Ti6yciat. The output does include several HTML elements, namely `div`, `figure`, `img`, `blockquote`, `p`, whereas what I want is to get as clean output as possible: https://pastebin.com/raw/LiGBMBDG

Comment: @jsx97 yes, this is expected and correct. Elements that cannot be expressed in Markdown syntax, such as figures, are output as HTML. You can prevent that by using `-t gfm-raw_html` and, to avoid losing the comments, modify the filter to set `el.format = 'markdown'` on the raw elements that you'd like to keep.

Comment: @jsx97 Please include this kind of information, i.e., input and expected output, in the question next time, this will allow us to write better answers.

Comment: Well, but "how to preserve HTML comments and to not preserve other HTML elements" is what my question is about. So in its current form, this code is not what I need, though the answer and our discussion are nevertheless useful on their own, of course. Could you show what exactly I need to do with `el.format = 'markdown'` (so that the code will work in the way I've just described)?

Comment: Albert's solution that really works for me is posted here: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/discussions/9514